# Best way to shift decimal in javascript currency strings

Tags: javascript, rounding, currency

So from reading around I know I should represent Dollar amounts (like $10.78) as whole integers (1078 cents).

```
My apps input is sometimes pretty ugly. Stuff like "$10.78533999". I know I can use parseFloat + Math.round like so:
```

return Math.round(100 * parseFloat(dollarsAndCentsString.replace(/[$,]/g, '')));

but I'm worried about rounding errors. I can do something elaborate like this:

```
Number.prototype.round = function(places){
    places = Math.pow(10, places); 
    return Math.round((this + Number.EPSILON) * places) / 100;
}

var shiftDecimal = function(amount){
    var amountDecPos = amount.indexOf('.');
    var intAmount = amount.substring(0, amount.indexOf('.'));
    var remainder = parseFloat(amount.substring(amount.indexOf('.') , amount.length ) ).round(2).toString().substr(2);
    return intAmount + remainder;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eg0as88b/1/

Where I have a custom (and I think very accurate) rounding function that operators only on the decimal fraction to minimize rounding errors.

Is this overkill? It just seems like there ought to be a better way (especially performance wise). Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about for display purposes or for storage & domain calculation purposes?  The importance of rounding is vastly different depending on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use **number.toLocaleString()** function.

This is an inbuilt function given by JavaScript to convert number into currency.

Ex.

```
var number = 10.78533999;

console.log(num.toLocaleString(undefined, {maximumFractionDigits: 2})); // Displays "10.79" if in U.S. English locale
```

Ref Link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: That does seem to work, it's got a little trouble when I try to get rid of the decimal (I had to use toFixed(0)). Do I need to worry about how toLocalString rounds? Here's a JSFiddle of the whole thing: 

https://jsfiddle.net/xcrc09L4/3/

Comment: You don't need to worry about toLocalString rounds. If my solution worked for you then please make my answer as answered. & also up the answer. So other your know this answer is correct